# The next term is?

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

A sequence of integers between 0 and 9 is as follows:

> 5, 8, 1, 0, 1, 8, 6, 2, 4, ?

What is the next term?

Hint:

> How familiar are you with modular arithmetic?

Comment: Is `0` between `1` and `10`?

Comment: Not sure how you can go from 0 to 1 with modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have an Idea but I'm not sure if this is correct:

> we have **5** *+3* **8** *-7* **1** *-1* **0** *+1* **1** *+7* **8** *-2* **6** *-4* **2** *+2* **4**

If we now grab the italic numbers we have:

> +3-7-1+1+7-2-4+2 = **-1**

If we take the row:

> 5, 8, 1, 0, 1, 8, 6, 2, 4, and add this 
> -1 we get the number **3**

Comment: Please hide answers so others have a chance to try it.

Comment: Yeah i wanne to but i didnt find out how to ty for your correction

Comment: Try thinking of the differences as additions rather than additions or subtractions.

Answer (score -3):

> The next term is 8
> Take 0 as middle number and compare left side and right side:
> 7,3,1,5,8,1,0,1,8,6,2,4, 8

Comment: Could you explain this answer a bit more?

Comment: This seems to be a guess as to the preceding numbers that aren't supplied.